# How can I write a mock for GraphQL subscriptions/websockets using CodeceptJS?

Tags: websocket, graphql, e2e-testing, graphql-subscriptions, codeceptjs

if we have http reqest we write mock like this

```
      this.mockRoute(
        'https://<endpoint>*',
        (route) => {
          route.fulfill({
            status: 200,
            json: jsonMock
          })
        }
      )
```

i whould like to know how to write mock for subsciptions

the easyest way is just try to write,but as expected it diesnt work

```
     this.mockRoute(
        'wss://<endpoint>*',
        (route) => {
          route.fulfill({
            status: 200,
            json: jsonMock
          })
        }
      )
```